# How close to $-3$do we have to take $x$, so that $(x+3)^{-4} > 10,000?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm working on question $43$ in section 1.7 of Stewart Calculus, 8e. It goes as follows:

How close to $-3$ do we have to take x so that $1/(x+3)^4 > 10,000$?

Using the wonderful tool of Desmos, I was able to determine that $f(x) = 10,000$ for $x = -3.1$ and $x = -2.9$. So, in epsilon-delta language, if $|x+3|<0.1$, then $f(x)>10,000$

Now, what exactly is the problem here? I'm not satisfied with this "lucky guess" answer. I'd like to be able to express the whole thing in epsilon-delta form, but since no limits or epsilons are mentioned, I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: Basically, you want to find the smallest $y$ such that $y^4>10,000\to y>10$. So, the answer is $x>-3+\frac1{10}$,

Comment: So you want to solve $1/(x+3)^4>10^4$? That's the same as $1/|x+3|>10$ and so to $|x+3|<1/10$. No need for luck, guessing or *Desmos*.

Comment: Oh! This is about the precise definition of a (positive) infinite limit, isn't it? In that case, epsilons and limits don't matter, as the deltas have to be worked out case by case, is that right?

Comment: Wow, what rapid replies! Thanks very much, guys! I see the error in my thinking now :)

Comment: I just thought this was too straightforward/algebra-y for a section devoted to precise limit statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when $x=-2.9$ then $x+3=0.1=1/10$ then $(x+3)^{-4}=10^4$.So it suffices that you take $\delta=0.1$.
Proceed as follows in general for $G>0$, $(x+3)^{-4} >G \iff (x+3)^4<1/G \iff |x+3|<(1/G)^{1/4}$.So let us choose $\delta=(1/G)^{1/4}$.